# Navigation structure and uri problems

Tags: categories, navigation

I am using structure type entries for navigation with three fields for navigation that uses either: 
-customlink field (plain text) or 
-category
entry
as the source for links.

I have product categories setup like in this post: [How do I add a subcategory to the URL slug for a channel entry?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-do-i-add-a-subcategory-to-the-url-slug-for-a-channel-entry/372#372)

This gives me the display of products I want from each category. My nav output template for category navigation looks like this:

```
            {% if entry.menulink|length %}

            <a  href="{{ entry.menulink.first.slug }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>

            {% elseif entry.customMenuUrl %}

            <a  href="{{ entry.customMenuUrl }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>


            {% elseif entry.productCategoryLink|length %}

            <a  class="{{ activeclass }}" href="{{ entry.productCategoryLink.first | lower }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>


            {% endif %}
```

My category links work to display my nice list of products.
My products section is set like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4ia62jo7i8yo38/Screenshot%202016-03-04%2017.29.35.png?dl=0
with the section entry urls set to render an entry in the template 'flowers/_entry.html''

SO thats the setup for navigation and templates.

Two problems are occurring which I cannot resolve yet.

1. The entry links in my category template produce nothing. When clicking on an entry from the category  I get my base and site templates but the output at 'flowers/_entry.html' is never rendered. I cant work out where craft thinks the entry template for the category should be.

2 . My navigation links are inheriting the current url 
So if on the page 'mysite.com/category1' and i click on 'category1' in my navigation the url becomes ''mysite.com/category1/category1'

Have been round the houses for 2 days on 1 above. I don't mind a learning curve but I am in circles and not ascending the curve :)

Comment: Solved: so silly - my twig templates were using the wrong block name

Answer (score 2):

OP solved it with using the correct block names.