# Where to find info on Entry URL Formats and routing syntax/options?

Tags: templating, url, routing

Is there any documentation other than on the CraftCMS web site with details and examples of Entry URL Format options/syntax? I came across an [example from Brandon Kelly in this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-do-i-add-a-subcategory-to-the-url-slug-for-a-channel-entry?rq=1) yesterday which gave me much insight and a solution to an entry url issue of my own, and I'd like to learn more about this as well as Routing options.

Tips appreciated.