# Including the category group in nested category URIs?

Tags: craft3

I've [asked already](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20800/nested-categories-in-url-slug) about nested categories here, but I've just upgraded to Craft 3 and things seem to have changed a little.

I have three top-level category groups:

```
- Home
- About
- Funding
```

Each of these has multiple categories, and some of these categories are nested up to three levels deep.

My problem: the nested category URIs don't include the category group (which I appreciate doesn't have its own slug). Instead I get stuff like this:

```
/cat-A/subcat-1/
/cat-B/subcat-2/subcat-6/
```

... when what I want is:

```
about/cat-A/subcat-1/
funding/cat-B/subcat-2/subcat-6/
```

If I manually add `funding/` or `about/` as part of those categories' URI formats (eg. `funding/{parent.uri}/{slug}`) then it appends `funding/` at each level, eg: `funding/funding/funding/cat-B/subcat-2/subcat-6`.

I've managed to achieve what I want for *entries*, by setting their URI format like so:

```
{category.first().group.handle}/{category.last().uri}/{parent.uri}/{slug}
```

... which gives me stuff like:

```
funding/cat-B/subcat-2/subcat-6/entry-title-slug
```

I only really need this feature to work because I envision users browsing the categories and potentially clicking the URI/links and being taken to the wrong place.

In my earlier post I created a top-level category group called "Navigation" which contained all my categories – this achieved the correct URIs. This feels messy/hacky though and means my users have to see a redundant "Navigation" group when editing categories.

It's likely I'm misunderstanding some aspect of Craft here – can anyone help me achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I can't tell... is this specific to Craft 3 or do you have the same issue on Craft 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a Craft 3 only issue. The following should work on Craft 2:

Top-level Category: something/{slug}

Nested Category: {parent.uri}/{slug}

Comment: Thanks – I ended up making a top-level "Navigation" category group and then added all my categories under that. I then used a section with this Entry URI format: `{category.last().uri}/{parent.uri}/{slug}`.

Answer (score 2):

You would just enter `{ parent? parent.slug : '' }/{ slug }` in the "Category URI Format" Field in the Craft3 CP and it will recognize nested categories

Answer (score 2):

You can use Twig logic in you **Category URL Format** like this:

`{parent ? parent.uri : group.handle }/{slug}`

This will prepend the category group's handle (main, about, funding, etc.) if it's a top-level category (no parent). Otherwise it prepends the parent category's full URI.

Given you have a Category Group called **"About"** with the handle **"about,"** and that group has nested categories like this:

```
|-- cat-1
|   |-- cat-1-1
|   |-- cat-1-2
|       |-- cat-1-2-1
|
|-- cat-2
```

You'll get URIs like this:

```
/about/cat-1
/about/cat-1/cat-1-1
/about/cat-1/cat-1-2
/about/cat-1/cat-1-2/cat-1-2-1
/about/cat-2
```